# Cant combine PHPfreechat and Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to implement an onscreen jquery keyboard into my PHPfreechat client.

Everything works fine except when i try to link to the jquery script file. then the chat wont load.

im loading the jquery from my CDN but i have also tried local.

if i create a blank page with the jquery and keyboard scripts everything works fine.

not sure why this is blocking for the rest of the scripts and php on my chat.

any suggestions?

edit: furthermore i have also tried moving the load of the script files from top to bottom of the other scripts. if i load the jquery at the end of my scripts the keyboard works but the chat wont load. if i load it at the start the keyboard doesnt load but the chat works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to phpfreechat v2 it has been recoded from scratch and it uses JQuery instead of Prototype client side.
The client is a JQuery plugin, here is the code: https://github.com/kerphi/phpfreechat/tree/master/client

Answer (score 1):

php is running on the server, so I doubt the jquery include is causing anything over there.
I would suggest running your web in GoogleChrome or FireBug to see what's the actual error showing up in the Error Console, that will help your further!!

UPDATE:

seems you are mixing Prototype AND jQuery at the same page - there are some known issues with that, and [even a solution](http://www.davidlano.com/2009/03/31/how-to-make-jquery-prototype-play-nice/), but personally I'd try to stick to only one js library to avoid any conflicts (so either Prototype OR jQuery)

Comment: im getting an error stating that my htmldocument has no function called ready (this is the function that calls the keyboard)

Comment: so you use `$(document).ready(function(e){ do your thing });` or what? do you have a ready() function in your code? seems like something is not getting found to be included

Comment: i am using the exact same thing:

    `$(document).ready(function(e){ do your thing });`

Comment: so if "do your thing" is actual an alert does it work? If not, the jquery is not correctly included (or it can't find it). again, load up your javascript error console and look at the network/errors tabs

Comment: it seems my problem is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined"

Comment: exactly - your jquery file is not getting included - or at least not at the right order. It needs to be the FIRST ONE you include, PRIOR to your other ones

Comment: i moved it to the top of the document and now i am back at `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'`

Comment: sorry, you'll need to post your code in order for me to help you further

Comment: the update solved the problem with running both scripts at the same time. still no luck getting the keyboard open though. it really is troublesome to combine these two :|